# How do I make a task fail n amount of times before succeding?

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying out airflow's retry mechanism and I can't manage to make a task fail a fixed amount of times. For example, if the task has "3 max retries" I want to test what happens if...

- ...it fails 3 times and then succeeds
- ...it fails the 4 times

Nevertheless, the operators have "no memory" or recollection of past calls. The following DAG specification doesn't work because the counter inside the operator instance keeps resetting to 0.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import BaseOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

# Constants
from airflow.utils import apply_defaults

MAX_RETRIES = 3


class FailManyTimesOperator(BaseOperator):
    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(
            self,
            *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.count = 0

    def execute(self, context):
        self.count += 1
        if self.count < MAX_RETRIES + 1:
            print("Times tried: ", self.count, ". Times still to try: ", MAX_RETRIES - self.count)
            raise Exception("Manual failure")
        else:
            print("Job finished successfully")


# Default (but overridable) arguments for Operators instantiations
default_args = {
    'owner': 'Satan',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 11, 28),
    'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=2),
}


# DAG definition
dag = DAG('exp_1', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1))

# Use dag as python context so all tasks are "automagically" linked (in no specific order) to it
with dag:
    # Tasks definitions
    task_that_may_fail = FailManyTimesOperator(
        task_id='task_that_may_fail',
        provide_context=False,
        retries=MAX_RETRIES,
    )

    print_success_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='print_success',
        provide_context=False,
        python_callable=lambda : print("DAG finished successfully."),
    )

# Set tasks precedence
dag >> task_that_may_fail >> print_success_task
```

Is there a way to force a task to fail as many times as I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot tell you why your own counter is getting reset on every retry, but you can track the number of tries (note: tries, not retries) using `TaskInstance`'s builtin counter.

First set `provide_context=True` for `FailManyTimesOperator` and then in `execute()` use

```
context["task_instance"].try_number
```

to get the current number of tries.